Does order by in a window function add more frames?
Using :
sum(Age) over(partition by Country) as Total

Id          FirstName       LastName   Age         Country         Total      
----------- --------------- ---------- ----------- --------------- -----------
          5 Betty           Doe                 28 UAE                      28
          6 Fred            XXX                  1 UK                    99731
          7 Angela          XXX                 37 UK                    99731
          8 Dave            XXX               2000 UK                    99731
          9 Tony            YYY               9000 UK                    99731
         10 Tony            ZZZ                323 UK                    99731
         11 Pete            ZZZ              88323 UK                    99731
          3 David           Robinson            22 UK                    99731
          4 John            Reinhardt           25 UK                    99731
          1 John            Doe                 31 USA                      53
          2 Robert          Luna                22 USA                      53

I get what I expected. Which is for all the rows to be split into 3 "frames" (UAE, UK and USA), and the sum of the ages in each frame computed.
However with :
sum(Age) over(partition by Country order by LastName) as Total

Id          FirstName       LastName   Age         Country         Total      
----------- --------------- ---------- ----------- --------------- -----------
          5 Betty           Doe                 28 UAE                      28
          4 John            Reinhardt           25 UK                       25
          3 David           Robinson            22 UK                       47
          6 Fred            XXX                  1 UK                     2085
          7 Angela          XXX                 37 UK                     2085
          8 Dave            XXX               2000 UK                     2085
          9 Tony            YYY               9000 UK                    11085
         10 Tony            ZZZ                323 UK                    99731
         11 Pete            ZZZ              88323 UK                    99731
          1 John            Doe                 31 USA                      31
          2 Robert          Luna                22 USA                      53

I am not entirely sure what is happening.
It looks as though it is using the combination of "County" and "LastName" to create multiple frames, so the UK ones look to be
UK,Reinhardt
UK,Robinson
UK,XXX
UK,YYY
UK,ZZZ
And then it's computing the total in each of these frames. Almost like a GroupBy with 2 parameters, Group by Country, LastName and then summing these up as it goes through each row.
If that is the case, what is exactly happening with the following? and why doesn't it sum up each frame like it was doing above?
sum(Age) over(partition by Country, LastName order by FirstName) as Total

Id          FirstName       LastName   Age         Country         Total      
----------- --------------- ---------- ----------- --------------- -----------
          5 Betty           Doe                 28 UAE                      28
          4 John            Reinhardt           25 UK                       25
          3 David           Robinson            22 UK                       22
          7 Angela          XXX                 37 UK                       37
          8 Dave            XXX               2000 UK                     2037
          6 Fred            XXX                  1 UK                     2038
          9 Tony            YYY               9000 UK                     9000
         11 Pete            ZZZ              88323 UK                    88323
         10 Tony            ZZZ                323 UK                    88646
          1 John            Doe                 31 USA                      31
          2 Robert          Luna                22 USA                      22

Below is the test code
-- create
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  Id int,
  FirstName varchar(15),
  LastName varchar(10),
  Age int,
  Country varchar(15)
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe', 31, 'USA');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (2, 'Robert', 'Luna', 22, 'USA');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (3, 'David', 'Robinson', 22, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (4, 'John', 'Reinhardt', 25, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (5, 'Betty', 'Doe', 28, 'UAE');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (6, 'Fred', 'XXX', 1, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (7, 'Angela', 'XXX', 37, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (8, 'Dave', 'XXX', 2000, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (9, 'Tony', 'YYY', 9000, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (10, 'Tony', 'ZZZ', 323, 'UK');
INSERT INTO Customer(Id,FirstName,LastName,Age,Country) VALUES (11, 'Pete', 'ZZZ', 88323, 'UK');


SELECT 
    Id,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    Country,
    sum(Age) over(partition by Country) as Total
    --sum(Age) over(partition by Country order by LastName) as Total
    --sum(Age) over(partition by Country, LastName order by FirstName) as Total
FROM Customer


The answer is no. Without an ORDER BY clause (at the end), the result order is undefined. The order you get is according to the order the optimizer finds fastest to return, and might become different if data distribution/statistics change, or the dbms is upgraded.

On a side note, if you do want cumulative sum then you almost certainly also want rows unbounded preceding, which is subtly different from the default range unbounded preceding.

Adding order by LastName returns not separate frames, but a cumulative sum of all rows up to (and including) the current row (using LastName order) within each frame.
With partition by Country, LastName order by FirstName you are creating a frame for each Country, LastName combo, and returning the cumulative sum (using FirstName order) within each frame.

I see, so the only operation that creates new frames is partition?


PARTITION BY Country:

In this code, you are partitioning by Country, so each partition consists of all rows from the same Country.
SELECT 
    Id,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    Country,
    sum(Age) over(partition by Country) as Total
FROM sys.Customer

The output for this,



Id
FirstName
LastName
Age
Country
Total




5
Betty
Doe
28
UAE
28


3
David
Robinson
22
UK
99731


4
John
Reinhardt
25
UK
99731


6
Fred
XXX
1
UK
99731


7
Angela
XXX
37
UK
99731


8
Dave
XXX
2000
UK
99731


9
Tony
YYY
9000
UK
99731


10
Tony
ZZZ
323
UK
99731


11
Pete
ZZZ
88323
UK
99731


1
John
Doe
31
USA
53


2
Robert
Luna
22
USA
53




PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY LastName:

In this code, you are using the window function as partitioned by Country but also ordered by LastName within each partition.  As a result, each row contains the sum of Age values from the start of the Country partition up to the current row (sorted by LastName).
SELECT 
    Id,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    Country,
sum(Age) over(partition by Country order by LastName) as Total
FROM sys.Customer

The output for this,



Id
FirstName
LastName
Age
Country
Total




5
Betty
Doe
28
UAE
28


4
John
Reinhardt
25
UK
25


3
David
Robinson
22
UK
47


6
Fred
XXX
1
UK
2085


7
Angela
XXX
37
UK
2085


8
Dave
XXX
2000
UK
2085


9
Tony
YYY
9000
UK
11085


10
Tony
ZZZ
323
UK
99731


11
Pete
ZZZ
88323
UK
99731


1
John
Doe
31
USA
31


2
Robert
Luna
22
USA
53




PARTITION BY Country, LastName ORDER BY FirstName:

In this version, the SUM function no longer aggregates over the entire Country partition but within smaller subsets of (Country, LastName), leading to different cumulative results for each subset.
SELECT 
    Id,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    Country,
sum(Age) over(partition by Country, LastName order by FirstName) as Total
FROM sys.Customer


The output for this,



Id
FirstName
LastName
Age
Country
Total




5
Betty
Doe
28
UAE
28


4
John
Reinhardt
25
UK
25


3
David
Robinson
22
UK
22


7
Angela
XXX
37
UK
37


8
Dave
XXX
2000
UK
2037


6
Fred
XXX
1
UK
2038


9
Tony
YYY
9000
UK
9000


11
Pete
ZZZ
88323
UK
88323


10
Tony
ZZZ
323
UK
88646


1
John
Doe
31
USA
31


2
Robert
Luna
22
USA
22



